# What's an easy way to view a copy of a text buffer as a hexl buffer

Tags: buffers, window, files, hexl-mode

I sometimes want to look at the [`hexl-mode`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html) view of a text file buffer in one window and in another window I want to keep the original text view.

What's an easy procedure to do so? -- Due to the fact that I cannot easily clone a file buffer, it means I have to create a new buffer, copy the content and then `hexl-mode` this new buffer. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: It's not hard/long to do, is it? How often do you need to do it? In any case, you could certainly write a simple command to do that. Or even use a keyboard macro.

Comment: Although `clone-buffer` objects when the buffer is visiting a file, I think you could detach the buffer from the file name (with `set-visited-file-name`), clone it, hexl-mode the clone, go back to the original buffer and reset the file name - maybe... The devil is in the details.

Comment: @NickD Your idea is not quite riight: Evem after `set-visited-file-name` cloning is not allowed. **But**: I still can use this: 1. Set a new filename, hxl-mode that buffer. Reload the original into its normal buffer. Voila. *Slightly* easier than what I did before...

Comment: You have to `(set-visited-file-name nil)` to be able to clone it.

Comment: IOW, do `M-: (set-visited-file-name nil)` ; do *not* do `M-x set-visited-file-name RET nil RET`.

Comment: @NickD Aha, yes `M-: (set-visited-file-name nil)` works, but is _a lot_ to type... (so this would be only good if I write a custoim function for it).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a simpler way?

No, I think you have that correctly.  Something like this, then:

```el
(defun hexl-me-this ()
  "Open a copy of the current buffer in `hexl-mode'."
  (interactive)
  (display-buffer
   (let* ((buf (current-buffer))
          (mode major-mode)
          (coding buffer-file-coding-system)
          (file (or buffer-file-name
                    dired-directory
                    (expand-file-name (buffer-name) default-directory)))
          (tmp (concat temporary-file-directory "hexl" file))
          (hexlbuf (or (get-file-buffer tmp) (create-file-buffer tmp))))
     (with-current-buffer hexlbuf
       (setq buffer-file-name tmp)
       (buffer-disable-undo)
       (erase-buffer)
       (remove-hook 'change-major-mode-hook #'hexl-maybe-dehexlify-buffer t)
       (funcall mode)
       (set-buffer-file-coding-system coding)
       (insert-buffer-substring buf)
       (hexl-mode)
       (set-buffer-modified-p nil))
     hexlbuf)))
```

Comment: Does `make-indirect-buffer` not work?

Comment: It does not.  Indirect buffers share their buffer text, and hexl-mode clobbers that text.

Comment: D'oh. -1 for my reading comprehension today